# setup.py ld cannot find library that is present, paths are configured

Tags: gcc, shared-libraries, ld, cython, archlinux

I am trying to compile a cython interface to a C library using this tutorial: [Using C libraries with Cython](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/clibraries.html) but when I go for it with:

```
python2 setup.py build_ext -i
```

The linker fails to find the library (the library name is `libHorde3D`)

```
gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro,--hash-style=gnu build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/horde3d.o -L/usr/lib -llibHorde3D -lpython2.7 -o /home/kiril/workspace/horde3d_python/cython/horde3d.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibHorde3D
```

That is very peculiar as libHorde3D.so is present in my /usr/lib and in my /opt/lib, the search path for the linker is configured in /etc/ld.conf to look into these directories and I tried setting the search path with the following variables:
LD_LIBRARY_PATH, LIBRARY_PATH, LDFLAGS, as well as by passing it straight:

```
python2 setup.py build_ext -i -L/opt/lib
```

I did an `ldconfig -v` and the library is listed:

```
/usr/lib:
    libHorde3D.so -> libHorde3D.so
/opt/lib:
    libHorde3D.so -> libHorde3D.so
```

For good measure I tried to change the owner to 'root', still nothing.

What is going on here? Especially since i am able to link the library if the linker is called from Code::Blocks(when working on some supplementary C++ code).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to remove the word `lib` from your `-l` argument, so change it to `-lHorde3D`

Comment: That in fact worked, thanks. Weird that I have to link all my other libraries with the lib word.